# Prevent Eventhandler loop based on an event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code as follows..by which when a client clicks on call button a signal is send to another client and a sound is played at other client till he accepts call. The button turns to End call after clicking Call button:

```
function beginCall(obj) {
    console.log(obj.value);
    obj.setAttribute("onclick", "endCall(this,'" + obj.value + "')");
    obj.value = 'End Call';
    _stream = _streams[obj.id.replace("btn_", "")];
    var streamNames = _stream.name.toString();
    session.signal({
        type: "begincall",
        to: _stream.connection,
        data: { streamId: _selfstream.streamId + "|" + _selfstream.name }
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("signal error: " + error.reason);
        } else {
            console.log("signal sent: begincall:");
        }
    });
}

function signalEventHandler(event) {    
    if (event.type == "signal:begincall") {
        //sound alert   
        var audio = new Audio('inc/sound.mp3');
        audio.loop = true;
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

The issue is that after clicking on call button and if the same client clicks on end call button again and again before the other person accepts the call, multiple audio gets played as loop.

I need to make the audio play only once based on

```
if (event.type == "signal:begincall") {
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to bind your event handlers then use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) at the end of the handler function to remove it.

Comment: @André Dion Could you please provide me few more details so that i can understand it. I am new to javascript.

Comment: Nobody to help me on this issue ??

Comment: No one is going to write your code for you. Read the documentation I've linked to, make an attempt and _then_ ask for help if you encounter issues. As an aside, using [stock photos of models](https://tineye.com/search/d3e6ad3a628903fcfac485f5d55001764ac01a5b/) as your profile image to solicit help is frowned upon.